# Adding border to a table row containing certain string in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that is being generated from my program and currently have a macro that replaces `<BR/>` tags with a newline. This signifies the start of a new section in the table so I also wanted to add a border to the top of that row where the `<BR/>` tag occurs. My current code is:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = "<BR/>"
    .Forward = True
    While .Execute
        .Parent.Text = Chr(10)
        .Parent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Wend
End With
```

How could I get the entire row in the table where `<BR/>` occurs and then add a border to it?

My attempt so far was to add at end of the while loop after Collapse:

```
With .Parent.Row.Borders(wdBorderTop)
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
    .Color = wdColorAutomatic
End With
```

But that does not do anything (also no error). I do not think I am grabbing the row correctly but I can not find any other way of doing it. Thanks.

EDIT:

I am now thinking maybe I should do a separate check before the newline part. So adding a for loop to loop through all table rows, check if `<BR/>` exists and if it does add a border to the top of the row.

I am not used to vba in word, usually use excel so think I might be mixing the two. Here is what I have got so far:

```
Dim oTbl As Table
  Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

  For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
    If InStr(1, oRow.Cell(1, 1), "<BR/>", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        oRow.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    End If
  Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working using the for loop way. My final code was:

```
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oRow As Row

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
    If InStr(1, oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text, "<BR/>", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        oRow.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    End If
  Next
Next
```

So this loops through all tables in the document and then all the rows in each table adding a border line above each row that contains the `<BR/>` tag in its first cell (which signifies a new section). I do all this before the next part of the code which replaces the `<BR/>` tag with the new line character.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.